# How to write trivial JSP that just returns static XML page

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to write a trivial JSP that returns the contents of a static xml file. I need to run this in tomcat. Eventually, this will be more dynamic, but at first, I just want to return an xml file. Can anyone point me to a demo for such a trivial beast, I'm trying to learn what are the minimum chunks I need to create the web app and install in tomcat.

Mucho appreciato,

pawpaw17

Answer (score 10):

Following this [document](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/source.html) is always a good start.

But you may have issues.

First, it's basically trivial to do something like:

```
http://example.com/app/mydynamicxml.jsp
```

that returns an XML blob. Just paste the XML in to that file.

But it won't have an XML content type. You can fix that by adding directives to the JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="application/xml" %>
```

However, that brings on MORE problems.

Specifically, an XML file CAN NOT start with white space. It MUST start with <?.

That directive will very likely insert a blank line in to you XML file.

So, what you really want is:

```
<%@page contentType="application/xml" %><?xml version...
```

Finally, there IS a JSPX version of JSP, which uses an XML syntax, and avoids all of those white space issues. There's also a directive to Tomcat that can eliminate the white space issue. But, out the gate, this is the fastest, "obvious" tact to take.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing would be to specify the content type as `<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>`

```
<%-- Set the content type 
--%><%@ page contentType="text/xml" %><%-- 
--%><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><entry key="key1" value="value1" /><entry key="key2" /></root>
```

Check out the article on [Sun site](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/WebAppDev2/)

Comment: I would be concerned about the space between the definition of the contextType and the first xml statement.  I think the xml statement has to be on the VERY first line for it to be valid xml.  I would actually place the first line of the xml right behind the contentType.

Answer (score -1):

Tried adding a trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" page directive, but that wasn't supported on my server.

The solution was simply to remove any newlines after any page directives.

Comment: the question was flagged (not by me) and downvoted (not by me), but maybe it can be improved by editing. I tried something, but it's not convincing.